# My DateAdd function isn't working in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access, gridview

I am facing problem with below query in gridview:

```
SELECT matno,
 MAX(SWITCH(deldate=#01/02/2014# ,ORDCASES )) AS ["1/2/2014"],
MAX(SWITCH(deldate=DateAdd("d", -1, #01/02/2014#),ORDCASES )) AS ["previous_day"]
FROM invorder
GROUP BY matno;
```

When I am running this query in access its working properly and my output is

```
matno   "1/2/2014"  "previous_day"
0       
1     125   
3      29   
4     551   
5                  641
6                  41
7                  511
```

But when I execute this in `gridview` in `asp.net` output is as follows

```
matno   "1/2/2014"  "previous_day"
0       
1     125   
3      29   
4     551   
5                  
6                 
7
```

Kindly help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Show the exact code that you are using

Comment: I am just configuring gridview with above query

Comment: Did you bind the value of `previous_day` in your .aspx page?

Comment: Yes I have bounded previous_day

Answer (score 0):

In many cases the `DateAdd()` function is not available to queries that are run from outside of the Microsoft Access application itself. Instead of using

```
DateAdd("d", -1, #01/02/2014#)
```

try using this instead

```
CDate(CDbl(#01/02/2014#)-1)
```

or, better yet (because it is unambiguous)

```
CDate(CDbl(#2014-01-02#)-1)
```